# Comparing lists in DBT jinja macro inside for loop

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am storing output of each column in a list for the below query

```
        select table,
               columns,
               flag
        from  {{ model }}
```

for each table I need to compare the flag. how do i get flag in list for the corresponding table

{% for n in table %}

{%- if flag[n] == 'False'  %}

I tried as above its not working its returning null value

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that jinja is a templating language. In dbt, we use jinja to automate the creation of sql that then gets executed in our data warehouse. Accordingly, data from your data warehouse does not (typically) flow through your jinja code.

`flag` is a reference to a column in your database, so to evaluate the contents of `flag`, you need to write *sql* to do that job.

The only exception is if you are using [`run_query`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) or a similar macro to pull the data from your database into your jinja context at model-compile time. But I don't see any reference to that in your code (and frankly that's a complicating detail that's only relevant if you are trying to write SQL dynamically). If you are just trying to compare the value from a record in your  database as part of your model, just do it in sql.

Comment: Yes i am using run query.Below is the snippet     {%- set results = run_query(query) -%}

    {%- if execute -%}
    
        {%- set table,column_name,flag = [results.columns[0],results.columns[1],results.columns[2] -%}
     
 {%- endif -%}

Comment: can you update your question, then? It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.